# Noun for “the version that I handed in”

Tags: expressions

At university, we get problem sets, I work on them and hand them in. Then a tutor corrects them and gives them back to me. On my website, I want to provide both (since the former is digital, the latter is scanned).

What would be concise words for

- “The version that I have handed in” and
- “The version that the tutor corrected”?

Currently, I have “My version” and “Corrected version”. In German, I would use “Meine Abgabe” which is “My hand-in” or so, which I think is more expressive than “version”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can let go of the notion that what you need has to be a noun, I would suggest “As submitted” and “As returned.”

Comment: It does not have to be a noun, it just has to be short enough so that I can use it as a recurring term in a table header. “As submitted” sounds very good, since it conveys that this is what I have done, which might contain errors.